# Struts 2 pages getting slow due to console logs

Tags: logging, struts2, log4j

I have disabled dev mode for struts 2 by placing below constants in the struts.xml:

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
```

I also set log level in the log4j.properties:

```
 log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR
 log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2=ERROR
 log4j.logger.ognl=ERROR
 log4j.logger.freemarker=ERROR
```

But, My page loads are terribly slow and lot of mime-type outputs can be seen on console:

```
 <mime-mapping>
 <extension>pptm</extension>
 <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-  powerpoint.presentation.macroenabled.12</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>/redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
15:53:28.524 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG c.o.x.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter - falling back to default type converter   [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter@3810f3d8]
15:53:28.524 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean - Rendering template /template/xhtml/form-close
15:53:28.552 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.s.c.t.FreemarkerTemplateEngine - Rendering template /template/xhtml/form-close.ftl
15:53:28.632 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG c.o.x.interceptor.I18nInterceptor - after Locale=en_US
15:53:28.636 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG c.o.x.interceptor.I18nInterceptor - intercept } 
15:53:28.637 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.o.h.s.OpenSessionInViewFilter - Closing Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewFilter
15:53:28.641 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
15:53:28.643 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
15:53:28.643 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: Are you sure your log4j properties file is in the right place? Are you actually using log4j?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.